# Python and kernel task over usage (OSX)

Tags: python, opencv, memory

I wrote a Python script, which analyses a stack of images. It works fine, but when I launch it after a while the `kernel task` usage skyrockets to more than 9 GB. Is there any way to avoid this? The code is quite long and it consists in a number of loops; the images are analysed using `OpenCV`.

Comment: You're probably not releasing the images after use. You can use Python `del` to release the image memory

Comment: I did that, and I also included several `gc.collect()`... It looks like I am using a leaking version of opencv

Comment: Try using [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) to see where you are leaking.

Comment: Thanks @mirosval. I managed to locate the leak